# C++ Fraction Calculator using Classes and Functions

Tags: c++, function, class

I am new to StackOverflow, and starting at a new school. I was hoping for some guidance on an assignment. The assignment is to calculate an expression involving two fractions, and output the result. I've been working on this program for days with the knowledge from my textbook, but I guess I am still confused on how to implement functions within a class. I know what I want to do with my values, but I am confused on where to assign them. I tried to read in my values, but when outputting, I get garbage. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;
  class fraction                                        // Fraction class definition
  {
int num,
    den;
public:
fraction()                                      // default constructor
{
    num = 0;
    den = 1;
}
void add(fraction f1, fraction f2)                  // addition fcn
{
    num = (f1.num*f2.den) + (f2.num*f1.den);
    den = f1.den*f2.den;
}
void subtract(fraction f1, fraction f2)             // subtraction fcn
{
    num = (f1.num*f2.den) - (f2.num*f1.den);
    den = f1.den*f2.den;
}
void multiply(fraction f1, fraction f2)     // multiplying fcn
{
    num = f1.num*f2.num;
    den = f1.den*f2.den;
}
void divide(fraction f1, fraction f2)           // dividing fcn
{
    num = f1.num*f2.den;
    den = f1.den*f2.num;
}
void output()
{
    cout << num << "/" << den << endl;
}
};                                      // end Fraction class 


int main()
{                                   // begin main
    fraction result;
    fraction n;
    fraction d;
    int n1, n2, d1, d2 = 0;
    char op;
    cout << "Please enter an expression containing two fractions:" << endl;
    cin >> n1 >> d1 >> op >> n2 >> d2;

    switch (op) 
    {                                               // begin switch
    case '+':
        result.add(n, d);
        result.output();
        break;
    case '-':
        result.subtract(n, d);
        result.output();
        break;
    case '*':
        result.multiply(n, d);
        result.output();
        break;
    case'/':
        result.divide(n, d);
        result.output();
        break;
    }                                               // end switch

    //fraction f1(n1, d1);
    //fraction f2(n2, d2);



}                                   // end main
```

Comment: Well, you read `n1`, `d1` etc but then never use them for anything. That seems odd...

Comment: I'm still working on the program and trying to figure out how to use my values. I read in the values, but when I put in a test statement to output them to check if they were the correct values read in, I got garbage.

Comment: You probably want to provide contructor `fraction(int num, int den)` in order to construct fractions `d` and `n` with user inputs.

Comment: How do you expect anything to work if you start with garbage? "Garbage In. Garbage Out." try getting the program working with some hard coded values before worrying about IO.

Comment: Also, you may haven't learn it already, but this exercise would be a good introduction to [operator overloading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators): `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and `std::ostream <<`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be posted on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: No @dalle, it's not yet ready for [codereview.se], as it contains known bugs.

Answer (score 1):

The actual answer was given in the very first comment of John3136. Hence, I struggled a bit but finally realized that you probably didn't recognize. So, I will elaborate this a bit:

In `main()`, you do this:

```
int n1, n2, d1, d2 = 0;
char op;
cout << "Please enter an expression containing two fractions:" << endl;
cin >> n1 >> d1 >> op >> n2 >> d2;
```

Stepping through with a debugger, you will realize that this part of program works as expected. After input of e.g.

```
1 2 + 3 4
```

the variables will show the following values:

```
n1: 1
d1: 2
n2: 3
d2: 4
op: '+'
```

Live demo on [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/IbwCAE)

Stepping further, the program pointer will move to

```
result.add(n, d);
```

Hmm. You want to add `n` and `d` but the debugger says:

```
n: { num: 0, den: 1 }
d: { num: 0, den: 1 }
```

The values of `n.num`, `n.den`, `d.num`, and `d.den` are there as you provided a default constructor for `class fraction` which effects precisely this.

So, how do you think will `n1` be moved to `n.num`, `d1` to `n.den`, and so on?

What's really missing is a constructor for `class fraction` to load members `num` and `den` (in this case of `n` and `d`) with the specified values.

You could introduce a second constructor. In this case, you can modify (and extend) your existing, also:

```
class fraction {

  private:
    int num, den; // numerator, denominator

  public:

    explicit fraction(int num = 0, int den = 1): num(num), den(den) { }

};
```

Looks confusing? I will explain:

1. I gave the constructor arguments, but the arguments got default values.
   Hence, it still can be used as default constructor. Doing `fraction a;` will construct fraction 0/1 as before. But, now, you can also do `fraction b(3, 2);` to construct fraction 3/2. You can even do `fraction d(3);`. This will construct fraction 3/1 which sounds reasonable to me.
2. I named the arguments equal to the members. Looks funny and, may be, a bit confusing but it seems to be very usual nowadays. (Actually, I learned this in SO a short time ago.) However, the compiler will understand this correctly (even if it is the one of MS).
3. I prefixed the constructor with `explicit`. This prevents that the constructor might be used for implicit conversion. *Without* `explicit`, the following would work as well: `fraction c; c = 1;` i.e. assignment of `class fraction` from an `int`. This is a question of design whether or not you want to support this. Implicit conversion can be quite convenient but the compiler might apply it where you don't expect it. I personally got used to make nearly every constructor `explicit` as I don't like to "lose control" of what the compiler is doing.

Modifying the above constructor as recommended you then can use your class, e.g.:

```
fraction a(3, 2), b(1, 2);
fraction result; result.add(a, b);
result.output();
```

Now, it should print the sum of fractions `a` and `b`.

A last note:

I consider O'Neil's hint with the operator overloading basically reasonable. You will find answers with code samples in SO. (Some of them, written by me.) ;-) On the other hand, operator overloading is just another handicap. I wouldn't bother too much about this. (May be, in a second version...)

Finally, I made an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate the above mentioned with sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class fraction {

  private:
    int num, den; // numerator, denominator

  public:

    explicit fraction(int num = 0, int den = 1): num(num), den(den) { }

    void add(fraction f1, fraction f2) // addition fcn
    {
      num = (f1.num * f2.den) + (f2.num * f1.den);
      den = f1.den * f2.den;
    }

    void output() { cout << num << "/" << den << endl; }
};

int main()
{
  fraction a0;
  cout << "fraction a0: "; a0.output();
  fraction a(3, 2), b(1);
  cout << "fraction a(3, 2): "; a.output();
  cout << "fraction b(1): "; b.output();
  fraction c; c.add(a, b);
  cout << "fraction c = a + b: "; c.output();
  // assignment (using default assignment operator)
  fraction d; d = c;
  cout << "faction d = c; d: "; d.output();
#if 0 // disabled code
  // This will work only if constructor is not explicit:
  fraction e = 1; e = 1;
  cout << "fraction e; e = 1; e: "; e.output();
#endif // 0
  // fraction from input
  int n1, n2;
  cout << "Input n1 n2: "; cin >> n1 >> n2;
  fraction in(n1, n2);
  cout << "fraction in(n1, n2): "; in.output();
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
123 321
```

Output:

```
fraction a0: 0/1
fraction a(3, 2): 3/2
fraction b(1): 1/1
fraction c = a + b: 5/2
faction d = c; d: 5/2
Input n1 n2: fraction in(n1, n2): 123/321
```

Live demo on [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/1rKgUZ).

---

After having read your comment, I'm in doubt whether you already understood the concept of `class` and member function. I'll try my best:

Are you aware that your function `add()` is a **member function**? It is as you defined the function inside your `class fraction`. That means, `add()` cannot be called without an object (i.e. an instance of `fraction`).

If you write this into your `main()` function you get a compiler error:

```
fraction a, b;
fraction::add(a, b);
```

Live demo on [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/d7Ujhp)

The object is *another argument* that a call of a (non-`static`) member function (like `fraction::add()`) urgently needs. May be, you didn't recognize the thing in front of the dot as function argument but it is.

```
fraction c; c.add(a, b);
/*          ^     ^  ^
 *          |     |  +--- 2nd argument
 *          |     +------ 1st argument
 *          +------------ object (which becomes THE this POINTER inside fraction::add())
 */
```

Hence, `fraction.add()` has actually three arguments. So, how may the object be accessed? For this, C++ provides a special keyword `this`. `this` is a pointer to class, and it provides a pointer to the object for which the member function has been called. Using `this`, you can access all (other) members of this class – member variables as well as member functions.

(Decades ago, when I tried to understand by myself how C++ and OOP are working, I had a look into the compiled assembly code. I was really surprised to realize that the object before the dot was exactly handled like the other arguments in the parentheses. This was one of my personal Heureka!-moments.)

Access to members (of the same class) can be done inside a member function with `this->` but it can be left out as well as the compiler will add this silently if applicable.

Your member function `fraction::add()` is actually a demonstration of this.
It gets two arguments `f1` and `f2`, processes their members (`f1.num`, `f1.den`, `f2.num`, and `f2.den`) to perform the addition of fractions, and stores the resp. results in member variables `num` and `den`. In this case, `num` is the same as `this->num` and `den` the same as `this->den`. So, where is `this` pointing to? This depends on the object for which the member function has been called. For e.g.:

```
result.add(n, d);
```

inside of `fraction::add()`, `this` will point to `result`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on why the fraction a & b are assigned values. I want my values for the fractions from the user, so I read those in main, but I am not quite sure how to pass them into my functions

Comment: @AnnieLee Examples for `a` and `b` show how to _construct_ fractions with specific values. The live demo on ideone (link at the end of answer) considers construction from input values as well. In case, you cannot open the link [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/1rKgUZ) - I edited the sample code, input, and output into my answer.

Comment: @AnnieLee I'm in doubt whether you got the concept of member functions and added some notes.

Comment: @AnnieLee After hard thinking again, where the "missing piece" could be on your side, I rewrote the answer a bit (from beginning).